# How to run files in the working directory through Git Bash and Python

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, git-bash

I'm having some issues running Python 3, which I installed with Anaconda, through Git Bash. I'm able to access the interactive environment by entering `python` but whenever I enter:

```
python webscraper.py
```

I get this:

```
C:/Users/[My username]/anaconda3/python.exe: can't open file 'webscraper.py': [Errno 2]
No such file or directory
```

The Python file is in the same directory I'm currently working in when I'm getting these errors. The path to my version of Python through Anaconda also looks like it's correct. I was previously able to test scripts in Bash but had to reinstall it to solve some other issue.

Comment: Did you activate the environment? Can you share the contents of the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if you are using the right python:

```
which python # in your git bash session
```

Then test it with the full absolute pathname of the file, [as described here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NoSuchFileOrDirectory/):

```
python /full/path/to/webscrapper.py
```